# How to Save Selected TableView Row Data and Show when user Come Back to Screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am Newbie in iOS Development. I want to make an Application that Contain UITableview. I want to Show when user Select UITableView Cell then it Like as Check marked it is Worked as i want but now i want to Show when User Back to Other View And Come back to Table View then it Shows Your Past Selection Of Table View Cell Please Give me Solution For that.

I Show in Stack Overflow it is Done by NSUSerdefault i find a code for it and Set like as But it is Not Working for me Please Give me Solution.

Here my UITableview `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` Method.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
CategoryCustumCell *cell = (CategoryCustumCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *selectedCell= cell.categoryLabel.text;
NSLog(@"Category label %@",selectedCell);
NSString *text=[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
if([self isRowSelectedOnTableView:tableView atIndexPath:indexPath])
{
    [self.selectedCells removeObject:indexPath];
    [self.selecedStates removeObject:text];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
} else
{
    [self.selectedCells addObject:indexPath];
    [self.selecedStates addObject:text];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
NSLog(@"%@", self.selecedStates);
NSUserDefaults *userdefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userdefaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.section] forKey:@"lastIndexPathUsed"];
[userdefaults synchronize];
}
```

And Also Code for UITableView `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
-(CategoryCustumCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
CategoryCustumCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CategoryCustumCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
cell.categoryLabel.text=[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
cell.accessoryType = ([self isRowSelectedOnTableView:tableView atIndexPath:indexPath]) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
return cell;
}
```

And I write to Fetch NSUserdefault Data in viewDidLoad like as

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.lastIndexPath = [defaults objectForKey:@"lastIndexPathUsed"];
```

and i Define in my `.h` file

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath;
```

But i not Get Selection on User Come Back to the View Please Give me Solution for it.

Comment: Can you show code for your cellForRowAtIndexPath method? You need to generate cell view using NSUSerDefaults. Also are you using indexPath.section instead of using indexPath.row? Do you have multiple sections in your table view?

Comment: @NewStackUser i write cellForRowAtIndexPath code here and Here my Tableview multiple Section.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper- See my answer you can replace my property with your nsuserdefault values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a property like below

```
@interface ViewController ()
//I added this property to keep track of the selected row
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSIndexPath *selectedPath;

@end
```

Check if it's nil or value is present in indexpath

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //I added this if clause to select the row that was last selected
    if (self.selectedPath != nil) {
        [TABLENAME selectRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }

}
```

Set the value in didSelect

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// set here
    self.selectedPath = indexPath;
}
```

Comment: It is very helpful for me...!

Comment: Awesome! awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
-(CategoryCustumCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
CategoryCustumCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CategoryCustumCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
cell.categoryLabel.text=[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
if (indexPath.section==self.lastIndexPath) {
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else{
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
return cell;
}
```